# unclustered PrimaryKey and clustered index

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

In one of our tables there is an existing non-clustered Primary Key on a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`column, heavily used in FKs.

We now want to add an `IDENTITY` column and create a unique clustered index for this.

I do not need an explanation of clustered vs. non-clustered or about "what is a primary key?".

I want to

1. drop all indexes
2. add the new column with `IDENTITY`
3. create the unique clustered index on the new column
4. re-create all indexes

My question are:

1. Will the new clustered index be used as look up key?
2. Will the Primary Key use the clustered key?
3. What implications could be, using a clustered key and a non-clustered PK side by side?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Will the new clustered index be used as look up key?

Yes the clustered key will be the look up key.

> 2. Will the Primary Key use the clustered key?

Yes primary key always has a clustered index attached to it.

> 3. What implications could be, using a clustered key and a non-clustered PK side by side?

This depends on the usage of your table and the associated columns.

Comment: Could it be, that you missed the point? I do have a primary key which I want to keep. The clustered index would be a new index... Btw: A PK does not always have a clustered index attached to it. This is just the default behavior.

Comment: @Shnugo:- So you mean you have a primary key and you are creating unique clustered index on some other column?

Comment: @Shnugo:- Ok so my answer still stands valid as far as I think as clustered index affects the order in which records are stored on disk.(*And I am hoping that your primary key doesnt have the clustered index attached as there can be only 1 clustered index on the table.*) While look up the clustered index will be used.

Comment: If you re-read my question you'll see, that the existing PK is non-clustered. The main point is: Will the optimizer look for a clustered index for lookups in any case or will it first look for an PK even if it is non-clustered?

Comment: @Shnugo:- Yes look at my earlier comment, I have already said, `While look up the clustered index will be used.` While looks up the clustered key index will be used instead of the primary key.